# Printing an array using MASM with Irvine32 library

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

My program accepts 4 integers and is suppose to display them back to the user. When printing the values I don't get the expected results. I'm using *MASM* with Kip's [Irvine32 library](http://www.kipirvine.com/asm/examples/)

My code is:

```
include irvine32.inc
.data

msg byte "Enter a number",0

arr dword 4 dup(?)
len=($-arr)/4

.code
main PROC

mov edx,offset msg
call writestring
call crlf

mov eax,0
mov ecx,0

.while(ecx<len)
    call readdec
    mov arr[ecx],eax
    inc ecx
.endw

mov ebx,0
mov ecx,0

.while(ecx<len)

    mov ebx,arr[ecx]
    call writedec
    call crlf
    inc ecx
.endw

exit
main ENDP

END main
```

A sample run of my program:

```
Enter a number
1
2
3
4
4
4
4
4
```

After entering the numbers 1,2,3, and 4 the program should have displayed those numbers back to the user. The output I expected is:

```
Enter a number
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

If I modify the loop that prints the numbers so that I place the value to print in *EAX* instead of *EBX* with this code:

```
    mov eax,arr[ecx]
    call writedec
```

I end up with nonsensical output values like this:

```
Enter a number
1
2
3
4
67305985
262914
1027
4
```

Why is my program behaving this way, and how can I modify it to get the expected results?

Comment: What made you think that `writedec` expects its input in `ebx`?

Comment: @Micheal I used eax in the second loop but it printed some really long values. So I used ebx instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one real issue in the code that appears in different places. When you do something like:

```
.while(ecx<len)
    call readdec
    mov arr[ecx],eax
    inc ecx
.endw
```

You must realize that `arr[ecx]` is the same as `arr+ecx`. *ECX* is the offset in bytes added to *arr* . The issue is that each element of *arr* is 32-bit (4 bytes) since you declared the array as:

```
arr dword 4 dup(?)
```

What you need to do is multiply *ECX* by the length of each element (in this case 4 bytes). You can do that by multiplying *ECX* by the size of the elements in the array `arr[ecx*4]` = `arr+(ecx*4)` . This form of [scaled addressing](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall10/V22.0201-002/addressing_modes.pdf) only supports multiplying by the value of 1,2,4, and 8 in 32-bit code. Your code should have looked like this:

```
.while(ecx<len)
    call readdec
    mov arr[ecx*4],eax
    inc ecx
.endw
```

There is a similar issue with the code that calls *writedec*. As well *writedec* takes the number to print in *EAX*, not *EBX*. This code:

```
.while(ecx<len)

    mov ebx,arr[ecx]
    call writedec
    call crlf
    inc ecx
.endw
```

Should be something like:

```
.while(ecx<len)

    mov eax,arr[ecx*4]
    call writedec
    call crlf
    inc ecx
.endw
```

One other trick to getting the length of an array in *MASM* is to use the `lengthof` pseudo-opcode. Where you wrote:

```
len=($-arr)/4
```

You could have used:

```
len=lengthof arr
```

*lengthof* will return the number of elements in *arr* . *MASM* takes into account the size of each element size (in this case 4 since you declared *arr* with *DWORD* elements). There was nothing wrong with the way you did it, I am offering up another mechanism.

I highly recommend learning to use a debugger to step through your code. A debugger can be an invaluable tool that can allow you to see how things are progressing in the code and see what is in the registers and memory at any given time.